# Grid view item menu

Tags: java, android, gridview, menu

I would like to ask how to add a menu(three points with options like the actionBar has) to a grid view item? I need it to look similar to youtube's mobile application videos: they all have these three points with a couple of options inside of them. How can I achieve this?

Here's the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class teamTasks extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.team_individual_tasks);

    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addTasks);

    final ArrayList<String> listItemsTasks=new ArrayList<String>();
    final ListAdapter addAdapterTasks = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_box,
            R.id.customBox, listItemsTasks);
    GridView gvtask = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvTasks);
    gvtask.setAdapter(addAdapterTasks);

    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listItemsTasks.add("New Task");
        }
    });
    gvtask.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/addTasks"/>

<GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addTasks"
    android:id="@+id/gvTasks"
    android:numColumns="2">
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom gridView item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/customBox"/>
```